# Unity fbx export has resulted in a destroyed looking mesh

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, unity

Ok so I'm making an unturned mod and I made the gun model in blender and exported it into unity as an fbx. Now when I exported it and opened it in Unity, the model looked destroyed and many faces of the gun was missing. I tried switching shaders of the material but to no avail. I cant figure out if its something in Unity or how I exported the model through Blender.[image]

Comment: You have inverted normals. In Blender go to edit mode, select all faces and press "CTRL+N" recalculate normals.

Comment: Is the recalculate normals the inside option??

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is **invert normals to right direction**.

**In edit mode:**
Easiest way is select all faces by *"A"* > recalculate by *"CTRL+N"*. This work in most cases. Usally does not work in non-closed/un-manifold meshes

Second way is manually select normals which you need invert and press *"SPACE"* > start typing "flip normals" > *"Enter"*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't sure if your model has inverted normals, you can always check them in Blender.

Hit <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties panel, then go to "Mesh Display" and select "Display Face Normals as Line". This option reveals the normals in your model as a line. The lines should be visible as shown in the picture below (yellow arrows show correct normals, blue arrows show inverted normals. You will only see the lines)

[image: normals as lines]

To recalculate the normals for your entire model, tab into edit mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. If that doesn't change the normals on the affected faces, select those faces, go to the 3D Viewport Menu - "Mesh" - "Normals" - "Flip Normals".

[image]